# How to detect anomalies in multiple different IP addresses?

Tags: unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection, isolation-forest

Given that my input data consists of various destination IP addresses and its incoming connections from source IP addresses with country codes during certain timestamps, I would like to detect anomalies in those connections. This data looks as follows (a highly simplified version):

| timestamp | dst_ip | src_ip | country | conn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 10:00 | x0 | y0 | US | 3 |
| 2021-01-01 10:00 | x1 | y1 | US | 1000 |
| 2021-01-01 11:00 | x0 | y1 | DE | 100 (*anomaly*) |
| 2021-01-01 12:00 | x0 | y2 | US | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 13:00 | x1 | y3 | IT | 9000 (*anomaly*) |
| 2021-01-01 13:00 | x1 | y4 | US | 1100 |

Anomaly detection is based on these time-series data. As soon as there is abnormal behavior in the number of total connections, it is detected as an anomaly. Each destination IP address has various behavior regarding the amount of connections it should get, e.g. for the destination IP address `x0` it is usually to get just a small number of incoming connection, whereas for `x1` it is about ~1000.

I'm facing the following problem: right now I'm looping through each destination IP address in my dataset and create an Isolation Forest. This is inefficient and takes a long time to detect for each destination IP address anomalies. Normalizing the connection values won't work either, since anomlies are than detected only for the "higher values".

So, my question is, whether I really need to create for each destination IP address an own Isolation Forest model or might there be another solution, e.g. submodels, or any other suggestions?

**EDIT 1:** We are talking here about ~50,000 destination IP addresses, which means setting a threshold as a "magic number" for each IP address is not possible and it has to stay dynamic.

Comment: At the most basic level, anomaly detection is about learning what the features of a typical non-anomaly looks like, and then given a test example, you want to devise a way to measure the "distance" between the features of the typical non-anomaly and the features of the test example. From a quick look at your data, it seems that all you really need are some if statements. If `x0_threshold` is the maximum number of `conn` that you are willing to treat as a non-anomaly for x0, then you could treat any `conn` for x0 above `x0_threshold` as an anomaly. Similarly,...

Comment: ...if `x1_threshold` is the maximum number of `conn` that you are willing to treat as a non-anomaly for x1, then you could treat any `conn` for x1 above `x1_threshold` as an anomaly. How can you determine `x0_threshold` and `x1_threshold`? This could be based on your experience, or it could be done my minimizing the number of false positives/negatives via cross-validation. Also, I am not sure if this was intentional, but it seems that anomalies originate from countries outside the US, so another simple rule is that if a connection originates from outside the US...

Comment: ...then treat it as an anomaly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @mhdadk. I was also already thinking about setting a threshold for each destination IP address, but unfortunately, this won't be possible. Because there are about ~50,000 IP addresses and the anomaly detection has to stay dynamic, meaning no magic numbers. Regarding the country code, it was just an example.

Comment: In that case, you can continuously estimate your thresholds. First, you would need to establish what anomalous and non-anomalous data looks like so that you know which is which as new data comes in. Then, you could use either the anomalous or non-anomalous data to estimate thresholds. This could for example be the maximum value of the non-anomalous data. You would then re-estimate these thresholds as new data comes in.

Comment: Hence creating a new model for every IP address, which comes in to distinguish anomalous from non-anomalous data. This is actually what I'm already doing and it's not the most efficient way.

Comment: What you could then do is group IP addresses with similar thresholds together. That way, you can greatly reduce the number of models that you would need to create. For example, if you have dst_ip's x0,x1,...,x100, and you have 200 conn readings for each dst_ip, then you could first estimate the thresholds for all x0,x1,...,x100, and then group them together using something like k-means clustering. You would then have x0 belongs to group 1, x1 belongs to group 3, x2 belongs to group 1, and so on...

Comment: ...This means that you know that once a new connection comes in, you send it to group X. You can then estimate thresholds for individual groups instead of each connection, which should be more efficient assuming the number of groups is much less than the number of dst_ip's.